# Offline testing of the Youtube player

Tags: testing, youtube

We have several integration tests (Cucumber driving Selenium) that work with Youtube videos.  Sometimes Youtube is down or slow which causes hiccups in the integration tests.

Has anyone succeeded in self-hosting the Youtube chrome, movies it plays, or both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Our approach was to write a mock Youtube player that responded to all of the same API calls and mimicked the behaviour of Youtube's player (e.g. getDuration() ticks up after the play button is pushed, etc.).  It took our ActionScript guru a couple of hours to write.

Here's a link to Youtube's JavaScript API docs for anyone who might go down this path:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Most of the methods do nothing, however there are a few with side-effects (e.g. the previously-mentioned getDuration() returns the real duration as the video would be 'playing').

Rob

Comment: Hey Rob, did you upload it? Is it possible to download this mock somewhere?